# Scrolling text in notification

Tags: android, notifications

I have a notification that contains a small amount of text but it still to big for it to be displayed in the notification bar so it is abbreviated. The only solution I've found it to make a custom notification but it seems a bit overkill for what I am trying to do.

Can I make the notification scrolling text or expand the notification text area so it will show the full text not just the first few words of it?

I currently call the notification with:

```
private void triggerNotification() {
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                "Title", System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "First text",
                "This is the text that gets abberviated with .. when it is too long",
                PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,MainActivity.class)
                        .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        nm.notify(0, notification);


}
```

Comment: What's your min-sdk supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In API 16+, there is a [Notification.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) class that allows you to add a [subtext](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setSubText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) which can be of multiple lines (Like [Gmail notifications](http://www.unwinnable.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/F127268090-576x1024.png)). I don't know if `Notification.Builder` is included in [the support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) but I guess it might be. You can check it.

However, if it is not in the support library and you have to stick to your minSdkVersion, I'm afraid that there is no way to do what you want other than implementing your own notification version.

---

**UPDATE:**

The last revision of the support library (revision 10 which was released on August 2012) introduces the Android 4.1 notification style: [BigTextStyle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle.html). there is a good example of how you can use it. Check it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle.html).